IntelliJ IDEA cannot autowire class fields
I have acquired a project in a new company where I am first time using Spring Boot and IntelliJ IDEA. Because of some out-of-date code, there are restrictions here, so, I can use the version 2022.2.5. Work is ongoing on this project for several years now, and we have currently dozens of customers.
In my code, there is an issue with autowired fields. Originally, the code I use was as follows:
/**
* The type OFLOW license parameter consumer.
*/
@Component
@Configurable(preConstruction = false, autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl extends CPSLicenseParamBaseImpl {

    /**
     * The set manager object.
     */
    @Autowired
    AppSettingsManager setMgr;

    /**
     * The app context object.
     */
    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appCtx;

    @Override
    public KeyStoreParam getKeyStoreParam() {
        return new OflowConsumerKeyStoreParamImpl();
    }
…

An NullPointerException was thrown at the getKeyStoreParam() call. The debugger showed that appCtx and setMgr are both null. To get rid of this issue, I modified the code as follows:
/**
 * The type OFLOW license parameter consumer.
 */
@Component
@Configurable(preConstruction = false, autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl extends CPSLicenseParamBaseImpl {

// @Autowired
// AppSettingsManager setMgr;

// @Autowired
// OflowAppContext appCtx;

   @Autowired
   public OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl(final AppSettingsManager setMgr, final OflowAppContext appCtx) {
      super(setMgr, appCtx);
   }

   @Override
   public KeyStoreParam getKeyStoreParam() {
      return new OflowConsumerKeyStoreParamImpl();
   }
…

This time, I had to add a constructor without parameters, as the program is making calls to OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl():
/**
* The type OFLOW license parameter consumer.
*/
@Component
@Configurable(preConstruction = false, autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl extends CPSLicenseParamBaseImpl {

//    @Autowired
//    AppSettingsManager setMgr;

//    @Autowired
//    OflowAppContext appCtx;

    /**
     * Standard constructor
     */
    public OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl(final AppSettingsManager setMgr, final OflowAppContext appCtx) {
        super(setMgr, appCtx);
    }
…

But the standard constructor had uninitialized autowired variables, which is not surprising, of course. As the parent class CPSLicenseParamBaseImpl is read-only, I added another abstract class inbetween and changed the code
/**
 * The type CPS license parameter.
 */
public abstract class CPSLicenseParamImpl extends CPSLicenseParamBaseImpl {

   /**
    * The application settings manager
    */
   protected AppSettingsManager setMgr;
   /**
    * The Orlando Workflow context
    */
   protected OflowAppContext appCtx;

   /**
    * Standard constructor only to be called after appCtx and setMgr are autowired.
    */
   public CPSLicenseParamImpl() {
      final String methodName = "CPSLicenseParamImpl";
      assertNotNull(Strings.printNotNull(methodName, "appCtx"), appCtx);
      assertNotNull(Strings.printNotNull(methodName, "setMgr"), setMgr);
   }

   /**
    * Instantiates a new CPS license parameters.
    *
    * @param setMgr the set mgr
    * @param appCtx the app ctx
    */
   public CPSLicenseParamImpl(final AppSettingsManager setMgr, final OflowAppContext appCtx) {
      this.appCtx = appCtx;
      this.setMgr = setMgr;
   }
}

to
/**
* The type OFLOW license parameter consumer.
*/
@Component
@Configurable(preConstruction = false, autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl extends CPSLicenseParamImpl {

//    @Autowired
//    AppSettingsManager setMgr;

//    @Autowired
//    OflowAppContext appCtx;

    /**
     * Standard constructor
     */
    public OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl() {
        super();
    }

    @Autowired
    public OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl(final AppSettingsManager setMgr, final OflowAppContext appCtx) {
        super(setMgr, appCtx);
    }
…

Additionally, as my predecessor advised me, I started the build.bat in the project directory:
build.bat:
CLS
ECHO ./build
SET JAVA_HOME=D:\tools\oracle\java
SET mvn=D:\tools\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin\mvn.bat
SET model=D:\source\workflow\orlando-domain-model
SET oflow=D:\source\workflow\vertragsverwaltung
SET portal=D:\source\workflow\portal-commons
cmd /c D: & cd %oflow% & call %mvn% clean -DskipTests
cmd /c D: & cd %portal% & call %mvn% clean compile install -DskipTests
cmd /c D: & cd %model% & call %mvn% clean compile install -DskipTests
cmd /c D: & cd %oflow% & call %mvn% compile install -DskipTests
cd %oflow%

and called “File” > “Invalidate Cashes…” to re-open IntelliJ. But still, I get over and over again the same error from the modified assertNotNull(Strings.printNotNull(methodName, "appCtx"), appCtx) from above:
…

2024-09-30 08:53:41,322 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] ERROR [o.s.w.c.ContextLoader] : Context initialization failed
java.lang.AssertionError: CPSLicenseParamImpl(?): appCtx darf niemals null sein!
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91) ~[com.springsource.org.junit-4.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43) ~[com.springsource.org.junit-4.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:524) ~[com.springsource.org.junit-4.7.0.jar:na]
    at at.cps.oflow.licensing.consumer.CPSLicenseParamImpl.<init>(CPSLicenseParamImpl.java from InputFileObject:29) ~[CPSLicenseParamImpl.class:na]
    at at.cps.oflow.licensing.consumer.OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl.<init>(OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl.java:42) ~[OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl.class:na]
    at at.cps.oflow.OflowAppContext.getLicenseParamImpl(OflowAppContext.java:346) ~[OflowAppContext.class:na]    
…

CPSLicenseParamImpl.java from InputFileObject: line 29 is the line where the assertNotNull resides.
Has anybody ever encountered this problem? Do you have some tips for me?
Edit:
I tried the following to get rid of the problem:
/**
 * Instantiates a new CPS license parameters.
 *
 * @param setMgr the set mgr
 * @param appCtx the app ctx
 */
public CPSLicenseParamImpl(final AppSettingsManager setMgr, final OflowAppContext appCtx) {
    initialization(setMgr, appCtx);
}

@PostConstruct
private void initialization(final AppSettingsManager setMgr, final OflowAppContext appCtx) {
    this.appCtx = appCtx;
    this.setMgr = setMgr;
}

Thanks to @M.Deinum's remark, the @PostConstruct can only be added to methods without parameters.
I removed this wrong code and here are the contents of the log file:
D:\tools\apache-tomcat-6.0.53\bin\catalina.bat run
[2024-09-30 10:37:14,297] Artifact oflow:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\tomcat\70124700-6990-4c5e-a690-605e8b503e65"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\tools\apache-tomcat-6.0.53"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\tools\apache-tomcat-6.0.53\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "D:\tools\Oracle\java"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\tools\apache-tomcat-6.0.53\bin\bootstrap.jar"
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51633', transport: 'socket'
30.09.2024 10:37:14 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.12 using APR version 1.5.2.
30.09.2024 10:37:14 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized with version OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 543 ms
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.53
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 40 ms
Connected to server
[2024-09-30 10:37:15,453] Artifact oflow:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
30.09.2024 10:37:15 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\source\workflow\vertragsverwaltung\target\oflow-1.7.18\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
2024-09-30 10:37:22,677 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  [org.zkoss] : Loading system default
2024-09-30 10:37:25,027 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  [a.c.o.u.ApplicationUpdateManager] : ApplicationVersion: 1.7.18(10718)10718
30.09.2024 10:37:25 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
2024-09-30 10:37:43,626 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] ERROR [o.s.w.c.ContextLoader] : Context initialization failed
java.lang.AssertionError: CPSLicenseParamImpl(?): appCtx darf niemals null sein!
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91) ~[com.springsource.org.junit-4.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43) ~[com.springsource.org.junit-4.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:524) ~[com.springsource.org.junit-4.7.0.jar:na]
    at at.cps.oflow.licensing.consumer.CPSLicenseParamImpl.<init>(CPSLicenseParamImpl.java from InputFileObject:31) ~[CPSLicenseParamImpl.class:na]
    at at.cps.oflow.licensing.consumer.OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl.<init>(OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl.java from InputFileObject:43) ~[OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl.class:na]
    at at.cps.oflow.OflowAppContext.getLicenseParamImpl(OflowAppContext.java:346) ~[OflowAppContext.class:na]
    at at.cps.portal.PortalAppContext.verifyLicense(PortalAppContext.java:98) ~[portal-commons-1.2.0.jar:na]
    at at.cps.oflow.OflowAppContext.onApplicationEvent(OflowAppContext.java:238) ~[OflowAppContext.class:na]
    at at.cps.oflow.OflowAppContext.onApplicationEvent(OflowAppContext.java:56) ~[OflowAppContext.class:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4276) [catalina.jar:6.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4779) [catalina.jar:6.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803) [catalina.jar:6.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780) [catalina.jar:6.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583) [catalina.jar:6.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1432) [catalina.jar:6.0.53]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.53]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:762) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:631) [catalina.jar:6.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:568) [catalina.jar:6.0.53]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.53]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:762) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:447) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1454) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:74) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1295) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1394) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:818) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_45]
30.09.2024 10:37:51 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error listenerStart
30.09.2024 10:37:53 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [/oflow] startup failed due to previous errors
30.09.2024 10:37:53 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/oflow] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
30.09.2024 10:37:53 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/oflow] registered the JDBC driver [com.pervasive.jdbc.v2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
30.09.2024 10:37:53 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/oflow] registered the JDBC driver [com.pervasive.jdbc.v2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
30.09.2024 10:37:53 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/oflow] registered the JDBC driver [pervasive.jdbc.PervasiveDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

Edit 3:
Here are all classes "headers" with @Autowired:
@Configurable
public abstract class EtlJavaDelegate extends LoggingClass implements JavaDelegate{
    @Autowired
    protected ABKEtlManager etl;
[…]
}

@Configurable
public class OflowActivitiEventListener extends LoggingClass implements ActivitiEventListener {

    @Autowired
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private GlobalTaskManager gtMgr;
[…]
}

@Configurable
public class CpsCommentListBox extends CpsBaseListBox<CPSActivityComment> {
[…]
    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;
[…]

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
//@Metrics
public class OflowAppContext extends
        PortalAppContext<OflowAppSettingsManager, OflowUserManager> implements IOflowAppContext, InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
[…]
    @Autowired
    protected SchedulerController scheduleCtrl;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
//@Metrics
public class OflowAppContext extends
        PortalAppContext<OflowAppSettingsManager, OflowUserManager> implements IOflowAppContext, InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
[…]
    @Autowired
    protected SchedulerController scheduleCtrl;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
//@Metrics
public class OflowAppContext extends
        PortalAppContext<OflowAppSettingsManager, OflowUserManager> implements IOflowAppContext, InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
[…]
    @Autowired
    protected SchedulerController scheduleCtrl;
[…]
}

@Configurable
public abstract class ArchiveModificationServiceTaskBase extends LoggingClass implements JavaDelegate {

    @Autowired
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    @Autowired
    OrlandoDatabaseSetManager dbSetMgr;
[…]
}

@Configurable
public class ChangeForAttention extends LoggingClass implements JavaDelegate {

    @Autowired
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    @Autowired
    OrlandoDatabaseSetManager dbSetMgr;
[…]
}

@Component
@Configurable(preConstruction = false, autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class OflowLicenseParamConsumerImpl extends CPSLicenseParamBaseImpl {

    @Autowired
    AppSettingsManager setMgr;

    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appCtx;
[…]
}

public class ScheduledApplicationJob extends ScheduledBaseJob<ScheduledApplicationTask> {

    @Autowired
    PortalAppContext appctx;
[…]
}

@Scope("prototype")
public class AppSettingController extends BasicController {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6530424942307347571L;
[…]
    @Autowired
    OflowAppSettingsManager appmgr;
    
    @Autowired
    LDAPSecurityManager ldapsecmgr;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ArchiveWorkflowTriggerController extends OflowCRUDController<ArchiveWorkflowTriggerModel, ArchiveWorkflowTrigger, ArchiveWorkflowTriggerManager> {
[…]
    @Autowired
    ProcessEngine engine;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class FibuDocumentController extends OflowBasicController {
[…]
    @Autowired
    OrlandoDatabaseSetManager odbsetmgr;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ImportLdapUserController extends BasicController{
[…] 
    @Autowired
    private LdapUserManagerImpl ldapusermgr;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserModel usermodel;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class KassaAssociationController extends OflowCRUDController<KassaAssociationModel, KassaAssociation, KassaAssociationManager> {
[…]
    @Autowired
    ProcessEngine engine;
    
    @Autowired
    OrlandoDatabaseSetManager dbsetmgr;
[…]

@Component
@Configurable
@Scope("prototype")
public class OflowMainPageController extends MainPageController {
[…]
    @Autowired
    private ReloadManager reloadManager;
[…]

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ScheduledTaskController extends OflowCRUDController<ScheduledTaskModel, ScheduledTask, ScheduledTaskManager> {
[…]
    @Autowired
    protected SchedulerController schedctrl;
[…]

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SecRoleController extends OflowCRUDController<SecRoleModel, OflowSecRole, OflowSecRoleManager> {
[…]
    @Autowired
    protected OflowUserManager usermgr;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class UserController extends OflowCRUDController<UserModel, OflowUser, OflowUserManager> {
[…]
    @Autowired
    OflowUserManager usrmgr;
    
    @Autowired
    GlobalTaskManager glbtaskmgr;
    
    @Autowired
    private LDAPSecurityManager ldapsecmgr;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class UserSettingController extends OflowBasicController {
[…]
    @Autowired
    private UserModel usermodel;
[…]
}

@Component
@Configurable
@Scope("desktop")
public class WorkflowmenuController extends OflowBasicController {
[…]
    @Autowired
    WorkflowManagerImpl wfmgr;
[…]
}

@Component
@Configurable
@Scope("desktop")
public class WorkflowmenuController extends OflowBasicController {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
[…]
    @Autowired
    DisplayTaskConverter conv;

    @Autowired
    TaskService tasksvc;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ActivitiFormController extends OflowBasicController implements ActivitiFormControllerInterface{
[…]
    @Autowired
    CachedActivitiHelpers helpers;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ActivitiFormController extends OflowBasicController implements ActivitiFormControllerInterface{
[…]
    @Autowired
    CachedActivitiHelpers helpers;
[…]
}

@Configurable
@Repository
@Scope("prototype")
public class ActtestPageController extends OflowBasicController {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Autowired
    ProcessEngine engine;
[…]
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class CopaDataActivitiFormController extends ActivitiFormController {
[…]
    @Autowired
    private OflowAppContext appctx;
[…]
}

@Configurable
@Repository
@Scope("prototype")
public class DeploymentPageController extends OflowBasicController {
[…]
    @Autowired
    ProcessDefinitionSettingManager settmgr;
[…]

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class KassaActivitFormController extends ActivitiFormController {

    @Autowired
    KassaHelper kassaHlp;

    @Autowired
    BirtReportUtil rep;
[…]

@Component
@Configurable
public class OrlandoEntityFactoryImpl extends LoggingClass implements OrlandoEntityFactory {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private final List<BaseManagerOrlandoImpl> mgrs = new ArrayList<BaseManagerOrlandoImpl>();

    @Autowired
    private OflowAppSettingsManager appset;
[…]

@Component
@Configurable
@Scope("prototype")
public class TaskWindowController extends OflowBasicController  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
[…]
    @Autowired
    TaskService tasksvc;
[…]
}

@Configurable
@Repository
@Scope("prototype")
public class DeliveryNoteSearchController extends OflowBasicController {

    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;

    @Autowired
    TaskService tasksvc;
    @Autowired
    RuntimeService rtsvc;
    @Autowired
    WorkflowManagerImpl wfmgr;
[…]
}

public abstract class ItemRowRenderer<T_DisplayItem extends DisplayItem> extends LoggingClass implements ListitemRenderer, InitializingBean {
    Callback callback;
    
    Class<T_DisplayItem> displayItemClass = (Class<T_DisplayItem>) ClassUtil.getTypeArguments(ItemRowRenderer.class, this.getClass()).get(0);
    
    @Autowired
    OflowSessionInfoManager sessinfomgr;
    
    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;
    
    @Autowired
    OflowUserContext userctx;
[…]
}

@Configurable
public class CpsArgeListBox extends CpsBaseListBox<CPSArgeBewegung> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;
[…]
}

@Configurable
public class CpsCommentListBox extends CpsBaseListBox<CPSActivityComment> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;
[…]
}

@Configurable
public class CpsDeliverynoteListbox extends HtmlMacroComponent implements CanBeReadOnlyElement {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2203783379685850861L;
[…] 
    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;
    
    @Autowired
    OflowUserContext usrctx;
[…]
}

@Configurable
public class CpsDocumentEntityAssignmentListBox extends CpsBaseListBox<CPSActivityDocumentEntityAssignmentImpl> implements Constrainted {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;
[…]
}

@Configurable
public class CpsKoreListBox extends CpsBaseListBox<CPSKoreV5Bewegung> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;
[…]

@Configurable
public class CpsReKorrListBox extends CpsBaseListBox<CPSRechnungsKuerzung> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;
[…]

@Configurable
public class CpsSachkontoSplitListBox extends CpsBaseListBox<CPSSachkontoBewegung> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Autowired
    OflowAppContext appctx;
[…]

@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContextJUnit.xml")
public final class VariableManipulatorTest extends OflowSpringActivitiTestCase {
    
    @Autowired
    OrlandoEntityFactoryMgr oefmgr;
[…]


THe fields will only be autowired after the object has been constructed. So checking them in the constructor will fail. The NullPointerException is quite logically as there is only a basic get method not an @Bean method so the object will not be processed by Spring. The OflowConsumerKeyStoreParamImpl should have a constructor accepting the needed dependencies or it should be a spring managed instance and that should be injected and returned from the get method.

Please don't add code as comments as that is totally unreadable. What I can decipher is that you have an illegal @PostConstruct method, that annotation is only applicable on a no-arg method, you have arguments.

Originally, when the code compiled and a NullPointerException was thrown, I was advised to close the IntelliJ, execute the build.bat file in the project directory, open IntelliJ IDEA (v2022.2.5), clean the cashes and reopen. Then, it will work. Once it didn't, so I was asked to redo it. And I had no problems.
